# Can I build UIView elements on a separate thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, uiview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an app that has to load and render a fair amount of content onto screen (mostly loading from a database).

I won't post all the code here but in effect it simply builds up a set of UIView objects that are added to a UIScrollView object. Nothing too complicated, just loaded quite a lot of stuff. This currently takes a second or so render everything (running on the main thread).

I want to show an activity indicator whilst the loading is happening, and I *think* the best way to do this is to have the method that takes a long time happen on a background thread and "report back" when it is complete.

The question is this. I know all the actual drawing is done by the main thread, so is it possible to create a new thread and have that build up a set of UIView objects that are then drawn on screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a great WWDC2012 session video, that deals exactly with your use case:

[WWDC2012 Building Concurrent User Interfaces in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/211/)

Basically the trick is to prepare and draw the views on another queue and ship it over to the main queue.

Comment: @moliveira, fixed. Thanks. Note, that you can edit an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. All the UI work should be done on the main thread. In your case I would suggest you to add the `UIView` object which are visible to the scrollview and add rest of them only when scrollview starts moving to that point. You can keep on adding views once they are about to be visible and remove any views which are not needed from the scrollview. This normally helps in better memory management.

Comment: «I thought you cant do any concurrent anything with UIKit, it just doesn't support it! Somebody on the internet told me so» «But somebody on the internet was wrong» — [WWDC2012 Building Concurrent User Interfaces in iOS](https://deimos.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/BrowsePrivately/adc.apple.com.16351493766.016351493772.16495242555?i=1800450331)

Comment: I am not sure about doing concurrent UI work, but one thing I can assure is we have to do it in main thread.

Comment: Wow if that is possible, then it will be really helpful. I remember till sometime back, we were not able to do any UI work in any background thread.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I recently watched that video and there was some useful stuff on that topic, but it left a (common - I would guess) issue untouched. They told about how to move some stuff like loading data from a network or doing some data processing to a concurrent worker threat. But what if you have for example a nib with lots of high-res images and stuff. I was working on a project recently where I had this exact problem. I had a UIViewController with a nib full of high-res images and I'd loved to able to load that VC on a background threat (continued in the next comment)

Comment: but the problem seems to be, that the loadView method of a VC is modifying the view hierarchy (even if you don't add the vc's view instantly to another view). So all that work needs to be done on the main threat. I tried moving a call to `someVC.view;` to a background threat before actually adding it as a subview, but sadly I ended up with empty views the got filled at some random point of time...

Comment: @Tobi, I think, nibs full of high-res artwork is not so common. at least they never crossed my way. There is another video, that might give you some hints: [Session 238 – iOS App Performance: Graphic and Animation](https://deimos.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/BrowsePrivately/adc.apple.com.16351493766.016351493772.16495242607?i=1239179764). And discussing your issues under someone Answer to a very different question is not helpful. Ask a new Question, where you also provide the code of your nib loading.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but I wasn't actually discussing 'my issue under an answer to a very different question'. Actually I wanted to say, that the question of the TO is close to my issue (because he's takling about building 'up a set of UIView objects that are added to a UIScrollView object', which is essentially the same what loading a nib does. And your link to the WWDC video isn't going to help on that ;)

Comment: @Tobi — there is no indication that this question's OP is storing any media files in nibs or about loading from nibs anyway, so most likely  it is a very different question.